# OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database ')

Tags: python, mysql

I wanted to connect to my tableau database source.
But when I run my python code it encounter error "OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'db_name'")"

And when I login in my tableau it encountered"There was an unknown connection error to the database. The error message below has additional information, but you might need to ask the database administrator to review the database logs.
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Unknown database 'db_name'
Unable to connect to the MySQL server "localhost". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database."

The code I used in jupyter is :
`engine_source = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}" .format(host='localhost', user="user_name", pw="password", db="db_name", port=3306))`

I made sure I typed every things right, but it still happened the error that I written above.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the database you're trying to connect to doesn't exist or you don't have the privileges to access it. There multiple things you could try.

- verify that the database actually exist, if it doesn't you will need to created
  -verify the spelling of the database name, MySQL is case-sensitive
- make sure you have the necessary privileges to access it. Run the command "SHOW GRANT FOR 'your_username'@localost' to see the privileges you have
  -check the port number you are using  is correct.